# Can my son be named 'Rafay'?

Tags: naming

Great information I got from this page About Islamic naming system.  Further I want to know about my son name.  His name is `Rafay`.

Please tell me is it right from Islamic point of view to name a child with that name?

I am confused . Hope Allah will help me and forgive me and will not harden my kids life because of my mistakes. Amin!

Comment: you can change his name if you think it would be.

Comment: why is the question title Huma Akbar Bukhari ??

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember, it is a nice name. Actually its meaning is fantastic by paying attention to its meaning which is related to Allah. Of course **it has some different definitions such as:
Ablator, ablative, resolver, soarer, but anyhow, on the whole, its meaning is positive.**

But seemingly you are confused and sad due to its meaning which is related to Allah.

In accordance with some narrations, it is better not to choose some names of Allah for children, such as:

Hakim, Malek, Nafe' and so on, but the point is that at majority of times, people who call other people, do not pay attention to the main meaning of their names, in fact their purposes are solely the individuals who are calling. (Not the name of Allah).

According to a narration:

> it is Makruh to name children from the names(Sefaat) of Allah. (but it
>   doesn’t mean it is Haram).
>
> و قد یستفاد کراهة التسمیة بصفات الخالق و الامر سهل‌"، جواهر الکلام‌،
>   محمد حسن نجفی‌، ج 31، ص 257

So as far as I know, a way which can help you, is putting the word "Abd" at the first of those similar names. How come?

For instance, one of my friends' name is Rahman, but we call him Abdol-Rahman, hence I reckon at least you'd better put the word Abd at the first of his name.
Of course it could be better if you change its name in his I'd card as well. But anyway, as I mentioned, at least you can call him Abdol-Rafay.

**Sources:**

- [dic.abadis.net](http://dic.abadis.net/)
- [www.askdin.com](http://www.askdin.com/thread1112.html)
- [allah_bande.persianblog.ir](http://allah_bande.persianblog.ir/page/005)

Answer (score 1):

Rafay is simply an Arabic adjective and common noun. When it used for God, it is converted into a proper noun by adding 'al' i.e. Al-Rafay meaning 'The Rafay'. Now, the quality being referred to is assumed in its ultimate form in Him. Therefore, to name some person Al-Rafay would be wrong. However, there is no harm in Rafay.